# How to store a field having datatype Number (35) (in Oracle database )in a variablein asp.net c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, devart

I am having a field as Number35 in Oracle database.I need to use this FIELD in ASP.NET MVC APPLICATION.  The application is using entity framework and devart  oradeveloper tool to connect Oracle database. I am facing the issue that when .edml file is generated through devart oradeveloper in Visual Studio 2010, the data type of that field is decimal and when I am trying to fetch a 35 digit number from the database, application is throwing error "decimal precision should be between 0 and 28".

Is there any if the data type generate through entity framework can changed to like Biginteger so that 35 digit data cane be fetched.

Comment: Try changing the datatype to `double` and re-run your EF migration.

Comment: What's the meaning of that "number"? Can you do some MATH with it? My guess is: someone mixed up the concepts of numbers and strings.

Comment: Please map number(35) to double like flyte suggested:
1) via the Tools > Entity Developer > Options > Servers' Options > Oracle menu (applied only for Entity Developer, *.edml)
2) using the Number Mappings connection string parameter (applied only for EDM Wizard, *.edmx)